# RabbitMQ server crashing

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

Version - rabbitMQ : 3.9.11, Erlang : 24.3.4.1

We are using nodejs process to publish and consume.
All of a sudden RabbitMQ stops responding. Even the web page would not respond (Dashboard).
Usage / RAM / queue sizes are normal at the time of crash.

If we see the log at crash time we got this:

```
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>     supervisor: {<0.21497.4>,rabbit_channel_sup}
**2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>     errorContext: shutdown_error
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>     reason: killed**
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>     offender: [{pid,<0.21500.4>},
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                {id,channel},
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                {mfargs,
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                    {rabbit_channel,start_link,
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                        [1,<0.21491.4>,<0.21498.4>,<0.21491.4>,
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                         <<"myserverip:59346 -> myserverip:5672">>,
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                         rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                         {user,<<"username">>,
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                             [administrator],
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                             [{rabbit_auth_backend_internal,none}]},
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                         <<"/">>,
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                         [{<<"publisher_confirms">>,bool,true},
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                          {<<"exchange_exchange_bindings">>,bool,true},
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                          {<<"basic.nack">>,bool,true},
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                          {<<"consumer_cancel_notify">>,bool,true},
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                          {<<"connection.blocked">>,bool,true},
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                          {<<"authentication_failure_close">>,bool,true}],
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                         <0.21492.4>,<0.21499.4>]}},
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                {restart_type,intrinsic},
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                {shutdown,70000},
2023-02-16 15:12:29.939986+05:30 [erro] <0.21497.4>                {child_type,worker}]
2023-02-16 15:12:35.434023+05:30 [erro] <0.21684.4>     supervisor: {<0.21684.4>,rabbit_channel_sup}
```

We are not getting any exception on our node process. It keeps publishing.

Please Help us to diagnose and solve the issue
Thank you.

We try to diagnose using rabbitmq-diagnostics cluster_status, but we are not getting any response from the server.
Server won't respond until we restart the service.